# Verify a login (username and password) programmatically

Tags: authentication, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin which needs to check if a given username and password can login a user. I DON'T want to log this user in. So `wp_signon()` is a problem for me because it programmatically logs in the user who owns the credentials.

Basically I need to do exactly what `wp_signon()` does, but instead return TRUE/FALSE instead of the automatic login.

Any advice on how I can do this?

Comment: Basically I need to do exactly what wp_signon() does, but instead return TRUE/FALSE instead of the automatic login.

Comment: Do you want to prevent bad passwords?

Comment: I already have the username and password. I just want to test that they match. It's for a single sign on API. So this client will send the username / password and my plugin will test them and return TRUE or FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that this function already exists: `wp_authenticate();`

It's just not documented in the codex at all! But you can look it up [here](http://wpseek.com/wp_authenticate/).

Update: There's an even better potential solution that you can read about [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61353/how-to-check-username-password-without-signing-in-the-user).

Comment: I misunderstood your question that username and password must be equal to each other.